# Import statements are missing in android eclipse and throws "project contains error(s), please fix it before running it" error

Tags: android, eclipse

Yesterday I have created a simple android application using eclipse (ADT bundle) and when I run it, it works fine. Today, when I try to open it, it shows errors

> Your project contains error(s), please fix it before running it

, and

> > cannot resolved variable.

After I go through my android application project, I found out that, all the import statement were gone. So I manually key in all the import statement and it works fine. This is second time I have encountered this kind of problem.Does anyone know why when I close the project and reopen it on next day, all the import statements are missing?

Comment: Just a tip - use CTRL+Shift+O to add import statements automatically instead of typing them out :)

Comment: If you close Eclipse and reopen it on the same day, is everything restored as it should be?

Comment: Yup it works fine @TedHopp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shouldn't be the case usually. You can try the auto import of the library needed instead of manually inserting the library one by one by `ctrl+shift+O`. Another common problem is that you included the library but it still cannot reference it correctly. Something like `cannot reference R.id.xxx`, that can be solved by making sure that you don't have import android.R in your code.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: does that always happens? if yes, maybe you wanna consider reinstalling your eclipse. Some time ago, i face the same problem after installing some additional plugins.